# why development tools like Webpack are not in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm new to nodejs/npm. Just a question on the package.json file. We know that when we install a new package by `npm install xxx [save-dev]`, it adds an entry to `dependencies` or `devDependencies` in the project's package.json.

But where there is no entry for Webpack in `dependencies`? isn't that it is the essential package that's required all the time? I mean when we use the cli to create the project, an entry of Webpack should be automatically added to `"dependencies"` because some essential packages are automatically added to the `"dependencies"`, why webpack is an exception?

Comment: None of my projects use webpack - it's not essential. Firstly, there's also browserify if you prefer that over webpack. Secondly, more and more of front-end developers using React have shifted to using package.json (npm itself) instead of webpack or browserify

Comment: @slebetman   I use Angular and it does use Webpack which is under the node_modules. So how come Webpack is not in the "dependencies" section of package.json even the application is using it?

Comment: Only direct dependencies (those you npm install yourself) are listed in your package.json. Sub-dependencies are listed in the package.json file of individual modules. For example dependencies of angular cli are listed at node_modules/@angular/cli/package.json

Answer (score 0):

**isn't that it is the essential package that's required all the time?**
=> No, it happens to be a popular package, not an essential one.

**I mean when we use the cli to create the project, an entry of Webpack should be automatically added to "dependencies"**

=> Which CLI? There are literally thousands of CLIs out there and each will have it's own way to create projects. If the CLI knows that your project needs webpack, it will add it to package.json

**because some essential packages are automatically added to the "dependencies"**
=> No, this depends totally on the CLI. Most CLIs just create a file based on template with some dynamic data and maybe some static data. If the CLI mentions some packages that are must for all projects of that kind, it will be created. This has nothing to do with node of webpack, rather author of CLI decides what goes where.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use Angular and it does use Webpack which is under the node_modules. So how come Webpack is not in the "dependencies" section of package.json even the application is using it?